# Lua - How to write / read arrays in to a text file?

Tags: text, lua, store

How can I arrays into text files using **Lua**?

For example if the array does not already exist in the file it makes the array. 
Eg. First time an **UniqueID(x)** gets a fruit and it is an apple it writes:

```
x = {"apple"}
```

If the array already exists then it just adds to that array's next position.
Eg. Second time the same **UniqueID(x)** gets a fruit it adds to the array:

```
x = {"apple","banana")
```

If a different **UniqueID(y)** gets a apple then it makes a new array:

```
x = {"apple","banana")

y = {"apple")
```

So in the end it would just be a text file that has a lot of arrays for different IDs.

Also, How would one read from this text file? So that I can call on specific positions of a specific array.

Comment: Always tag questions with the language

Comment: Ahh thank you I changed it :)